# rails で、 has_many しているレコードの個数でソートしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

たとえば、以下のようなモデルがあります。

```
class Post
  has_many :favorites
end

class User
  has_many :favorites
end

class Favorite
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

このとき、記事(Post) を、ユーザーによるお気に入り (Favorite) の数でソートしたいです。これは、どうやったら実現できるでしょうか?  Favorite は、 (user, post) にたいしてユニークです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rails 5 以上であれば、以下のように、 select, group, left_join を組み合わせることで実現可能です。

```
Post.select('posts.*', 'count(favorites.id) AS favs')
    .left_joins(:favorites)
    .group('posts.id')
    .order('favs desc')
# SELECT  posts.*, count(favorites.id) AS favs FROM `posts`
# LEFT OUTER JOIN `favorites` ON `favorites`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
# GROUP BY posts.id
# ORDER BY favs desc LIMIT 10
```